# pandas.errors.IndexingError: Too many indexers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

getting the error message too many indexers using pandas. code below

```
import pandas as pd
userlist = ['Smith', 'Clark']
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")  

for i, df in df.iterrows():    
    if (df['Last Name']) in userlist:
        df.at[1,'Runner']='Yes'        
    else:
        pass


csv:
Last Name,Frist Name,email,Runner,Vistor
Doe,John,jdoe@123.com,Yes,Yes
Smith,Shawn,ssmith@test.org,No,Yes
Brown,Beth,bbrown@school.org,Yes,No
Clark,Tom,tclark@work.com,No,Yes
```

I have a large data set with a list of names that need cell updates and will loop through the list to change the cells.  Please help.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
userlist = ['Smith', 'Clark']
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv") 
df['Runner'][df['Last Name'].isin(userlist)]='Yes'
```